# JMeter - Insert RegEx captured value as a variable into next request Path and into JSON BodyData

Tags: regex, variables, jmeter

I have the following JMeter test configuration:

[image: JMeter Test Configuration]

What I'm trying to do is the following:

1. Capture CustomerID as a variable using RegEx Extractor in the fisrt HTTP request
2. Capture ClusterID as a variable using RegEx Extractor in the second HTTP request
3. Inject ${ClusterID} as a variable in the PATH field of a third HTTP request
4. Inject ${CustomerID} as a variable in the BodyData of the third request, which is in JSON format

The problem is that the variables are not sent into the third request.
In the RegEx extractor I've entered NO_VALUE in the Default Value field, in order to check whether no value is captured with the extractor, but instead of the variable values or NO_VALUE text, null value is sent:

```
{
    "CustomerIds" : [ "null", "null"]
}
```

I'ts the same thing within the Path of the next request:

```
api/Clusters/**null**/Customers
```

Is there any limitation in sending RegEx variable into the Path or Body Data of which I'm not aware of?
I'ts a bit strange to me, because up until now I was able to send regex value as a variable into HTTP Header Manager and as a Parameter into the next HTTP request.

Any input on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: There is NO such limitation. Add `Debug Sampler` to your script and check what are the values captured into regex variables.

Comment: For some reason the regEx value was exported under Variable_Name_g0. JMeter added _g0 to my variable name. Don't know what is the logic behind it, but at least the Debug Sampler helped me to figure out what the problem was.
Now, instead of injecting ${Variable_Name}, I'm sending ${Variable_Name_g0} and my test plan works perfectly

Comment: your last comment suggests that you didn't specify "Template" (in regex post-processor) or specified it incorrectly. It should be something like `$1$`. That will cause the variable `CustomerID` to be saved, and you won't need to use `CustomerID_g0`. See http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#examples

Comment: Are you grouping the value you want to extract using parentheses? If yes, then you also supply template as $1$. Later, you can access the value without adding _g0

Comment: Yes, the Template is always set as $1$.

I wasn't grouping the Regular Expression with parentheses.

If the RegEx is NOT grouped in parentheses, then the results are:
'ClusterIdA=null'
'ClusterIdA_g=0'
'ClusterIdA_g0=58c40c37090c1a21b8c3ba96'

This is the reason why I used the ClusterIdA_g0 as a variable name.

If I group the RegEx with parentheses, then in the Debug Sampler I get the following results:
'ClusterIdA=58c40c37090c1a21b8c3ba96'
ClusterIdA_g=1
ClusterIdA_g0=58c40c37090c1a21b8c3ba96
ClusterIdA_g1=58c40c37090c1a21b8c3ba96

The parentheses solved my problem. Thanks!